# Step size for numerical methods.

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-theory

Is it true that for the method to be stable it always hold that:

For Euler's Method: $ h<\lambda/2$ EDIT: Is there a difference in this between the explicit and the implicit method?

For Runge-Kutta(4): $ h<\lambda/2.78$

With $h$ being the stepsize and $\lambda$ the eigenvalue.

Which eigenvalue should we take? The greatest or the lowest?

EDIT: Is there a similar formula for the trapezoidal method?

Comment: Which trapezoidal method, explicit (Heun) or implicit?

Comment: The implicit one, but the result for Heun, also interests me, How should I find this on my own?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation#A-stability and alsohttp://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168927495001085 if  you can get it. Also any textbook on numerical methods should have this information.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you probably mean is $|λh|<2$ and $|λh|<2.78$ if $λ$ is the largest eigenvalue and all eigenvalues are real and negative. This has to do with the stability regions (z=x+iy=λh)

[image: stability regions for RK 1,2,3,4]

If you want some kind of stability for more general problems with complex eigenvalues, one would have to chose something like $ |λh|<0.5$ for Euler and $ |λh|<2.5$ for RK4.